# Javascript label losing value after postback

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I have a datepicker in javascript. However after I have done a postback to the server, the label resets back to the default. I can not get it to keep the values that the user has selected.

I have tried moving my code around. But to no joy. The value always defaults back to the default. I am a newbie to javascript so maybe I do not fully understand the page life cycle.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
      startDate: moment().subtract('days', 29),
      endDate: moment(),
      minDate: '01/10/2019',
      maxDate: '12/31/2050',
      dateLimit: {
        days: 90
      },
      showDropdowns: true,
      showWeekNumbers: true,
      timePicker: false,
      timePickerIncrement: 1,
      timePicker12Hour: true,
      ranges: {
        'Today': [moment(), moment()],
        'Yesterday': [moment().subtract('days', 1), moment().subtract('days', 1)],
        'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract('days', 6), moment()],
        'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract('days', 29), moment()],
        'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
        'Last Month': [moment().subtract('month', 1).startOf('month'), moment().subtract('month', 1).endOf('month')]
      },
      opens: 'left',
      buttonClasses: ['btn btn-default'],
      applyClass: 'btn-small btn-primary',
      cancelClass: 'btn-small',
      format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
      separator: ' to ',
      locale: {
        applyLabel: 'Submit',
        fromLabel: 'From',
        toLabel: 'To',
        customRangeLabel: 'Custom Range',
        daysOfWeek: ['Su', 'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa'],
        monthNames: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
        firstDay: 1
      }
    },
    function(start, end) {
      console.log("Callback has been called!");
      $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('DD/MM/YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
      startDate = start;
      endDate = end;

      start = moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
      end = moment(end).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');

      document.getElementById('<%= Hidden1.ClientID %>').value = start;
      document.getElementById('<%= Hidden2.ClientID %>').value = end;
    }
  );
  //Set the initial state of the picker label
  $('#reportrange span').html(moment().subtract('days', 29).format('DD/MM/YYYY') + ' - ' + moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY'));





});

function TestClick() {
  alert(startDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY') + ' - ' + endDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />


<hr/>

<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="Hidden1" />
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="Hidden2" />
<br />
```

I expected the label value to retain the selection of the user. But once the page post back to update the new details, the label resorts back to the default date, but I need it to keep the selection of what the user has selected.

Comment: I've added a snippet into your question, which allows us to see for ourselves what's wrong. However the snippet does not work, it seems incomplete (e.g. what's `moment`). Anyway, you could try recording the values before the post back, and restore it after, but that's all I can help you until the snippet works.

Comment: Before posting to server save the date in local variable and set it again.

Comment: The label is not an asp label its part of the javascript time picker and is referenced by this  //Set the initial state of the picker label
  $('#reportrange span').html(moment().subtract('days', 29).format('DD/MM/YYYY') + ' - ' + moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY'));

Comment: JS always posts back to the default date as above. not sure how to keep it the same in JS

Answer (score 0):

You can you 'localStorage' and 'sessionStorage' to store data on client side.

 Example :

```
sessionStorage.setItem("name", "Smith");
var name = sessionStorage.getItem("name");
```